# Example of Holmested formula for real interpolation spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, interpolation-theory

Can anybody give me an example of Holmested formula for real interpolation spaces.

Comment: Please review [ask].  Readers will be encouraged to give helpful responses if you put your request in some context.  What did you try to find such an example?  What would make one interesting in your view?

Comment: The question was closed as off-topic. In the past I've studied this theory  but currently I've no abilities to create a simple example. Any case you have the genuine paper **Holmstedt**, *Interpolation of quasi-normed spaces*, Math. Scand. 26 (1970), where you can read Theorem 4.1 or Theorem 4.2. You can read the paper from the web of **Mathematica Scandinavica**. Additonally if you search in Google the words: *Holmsted formula, reiteration*, you find an article from Universidad de Zaragoza, where the authors BASTERO, MILMAN and J. RUIZ were using such formula in the proofs of statements.